# Provide part of a pathname (as an argument) to a npm script

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

Is it possible to read CLI arguments in a `scripts` entry of a `package.json`. I am looking for something like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "example": "ts-node --project tsconfig.json ./examples/${1}/.ts"
  }
}
```

where `${1}` would be replaced by the first argument passed to

```
npm run example yadda
```

and eventually run

```
ts-node --project tsconfig.json ./examples/yadda/.ts
```

*I know* I can write a JS file that can be called and run by npm that will read the CLI args, but I am wondering if I can read the args right from the npm script entry.

Comment: Take a look here https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/

Comment: @Emanuele that is from inside a JS script. That's why I wrote in the last sentence that I don't want to do that

Comment: A ok sorry, you are right

Comment: Take a look at my answer it it is what you meant

Comment: Ah thanks. A valid answer but not 100% what I was looking for. I will upvote it, but not accept it as solved. Thank you though.

Comment: Is your intention to pass a filename (minus the `.ts` file extension), or a folder name, to the npm-script as an argument? It's just that the `./examples/${1}/.ts` part in your example npm script seems to contradict my assumption that's it's a filename - it seems to be indicative of a directory/folder name instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax (not specific to npm itself)

```
$MY_VAR=foo npm run example
```

and in your scripts section do that

```
"example": "ts-node --project tsconfig.json ./examples/$MY_VAR/.ts"
```

Comment: Setting environment variables like that, (i.e `MY_VAR=foo`), will fail on Windows when the default shell is _cmd.exe_.  Also Windows `cmd.exe`  fails when referencing a variable with a dollar prefix such as `$MY_VAR` because the expected syntax is `%MY_VAR%` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your example command to run a script

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "example": "node --project tsconfig.json ./yourscript.js"
  }
}
```

Then in your script use the arguments

```js
var args = process.argv.splice(process.execArgv.length + 2);


args.forEach((value, index) => {
  console.log(`Argument ${index} is: ${value}`);
});
```

You could then call your script running `npm run example arg1 arg2` and use one of the arguments to import/require another file or run the specific code conditionally.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in my question, that is explicitly what I do not want to do (use a script file for that). Instead I want to use the scripts field of the package.json only

Comment: It's common practice to use scripts and no objective reason not to use them. In case you really want to, the answer from Emanuele is the only way.

Comment: Well, that there is no objective reason is an opinion and it is doubtful. In my case I don't want to clutter my repo with a script where I do not require any other build scripts. You know, clean code and stuff. Also, if there *were* a solution like the one I was asking for, that would probably be the KISS way to go. That's why I was asking.

Comment: No it's not, because it's the only way to pass arguments, as per the [official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) of npm run

Comment: Well, that was my question, wasn't it?

Comment: I'm not saying you're asking a bad question, on the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately npm does not, nor intends to, provide a builtin feature which allows arguments to be passed to the middle of a npm script *(as stated [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518#issuecomment-46915480))*. Arguments can only be passed to the end of a script.

Given that in your example you're wanting to pass an argument to the middle of a script, (to essentially create a new pathname), you'll need to utilize a workaround.

On *nix platforms (Linux, macOS, ...) the default shell utilized by npm is `sh`. Therefore you can utilize a [shell function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) in npm-scripts as a mechanism for handling arguments which are intended to be passed to the middle of a script.

**package.json**

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "example": "func() { ts-node --project tsconfig.json \"./examples/${1}.ts\"; }; func"
},
...
```

**Explanation:**

- At the end of the script, i.e. the trailing `func` part, invokes the arbitrarily named shell function; `func`, which is defined at the beginning of the script. Essentially the argument (e.g. `yadda`) which is provided via the CLI is passed to it.
- In the body of the `func` function we execute the `ts-node` command. The argument (e.g. `yadda`) is referenced in the body of the function using `$1` (i.e. the first [positional parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html)/argument).

**Running:**

Running the following command via your command line;

```js
npm run example yadda
```

will eventually run as:

```js
ts-node --project tsconfig.json ./examples/yadda.ts
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Windows, which utilizes `cmd.exe` as the default shell, will choke at the aforementioned solution.
2. You may want to consider also utilizing [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to provide a default value when no argument is provided via the CLI. For instance:

   **package.json**

   ```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "example": "func() { ts-node --project tsconfig.json \"./examples/${1:-foobar}.ts\"; }; func"
                                                                          ^^^^^^^^
   },
   ...
   ```

   Note the `${1:-foobar}` part instead of just `${1}`. This means that running the script without providing an argument. For instance:

   ```
   npm run example
   ```

   will eventually run as:

   ```
   ts-node --project tsconfig.json ./examples/foobar.ts
                                              ^^^^^^
   ```

   However, when an argument is provided, such as:

   ```
   npm run example yadda
   ```

   it will still run as before, i.e.

   ```js
   ts-node --project tsconfig.json ./examples/yadda.ts
   ```

---

**Cross-platform:**

If a cross platform solution, i.e. one that runs with both `sh` and `cmd.exe`, is required then you're left with really only one option, which is as you say: *"write a JS file that can be called and run by npm that will read the CLI args [ ...using [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) and shell-out the `ts-node` command using [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) or [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) ]*

Comment: If the argument is intended to be a folder name and not a filename (as per the question in my earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236876/using-cli-arguments-in-npm-script/57253009#comment-101006810) ) then just reinstate the forward slash, after the `${1}` part accordingly.